# backdrop and navigation bar on home page flutter

Tags: flutter-layout

I am not sure this question relates here but I seriously need to know how to have a backdrop and also a navigation bar at the same time on the same page. I tried to write the code but I am stuck at having two "body" in the same Scaffold

Comment: I have create sample in flutter with bottom navigation check the code https://github.com/driftycode/emirates-dialer/blob/master/lib/home.dart

Comment: Can you provide more details on your question? What do you mean with "two body"?

Comment: I meant I have a homepage in that I am trying put a backdrop and also a bottom navigation bar. But not able to put in the flutter code form. Hope you understood.